# Is allowed a mixture of POST/JSON data in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

I have the following code, in which a client-side call is made to the server via a jQuery AJAX method. The result is retorned in JSON by the server. All works fine, but I find the "replace" needed to parse the data somehow cumbersome and strange, and if I do not supress the "[" and "]" characters, the code simply does not work. Any suggestion on how it could be improved?

Client-side code:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/cart_update.php?lang=en',
    data: { 
        'id': id ,
        'incr' : increment,
        'quantity' : jQuery("#quantity_number" + id).val(), 
        'final_quantity' : final_quantity,
    },
    success: function(data){
        var data = data.replace("[", "");
        data = data.replace("]", "");
        if(data != ""){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            jQuery("#quantity_number" + id).val(obj.quantity);
            jQuery("#total" + id).html(obj.price);
        } // if
    }
});
```

Server (PHP) code:

```
 ... some SQL query...

 $value[0]["quantity"] = $row->quantity;
 $value[0]["price"] = get_price_product($row->id_product, $row->quantity);

 echo json_encode($value);
```

With the output being a string: [{"quantity": "8", "price": "$1,756.00"}]

Why I need to supress the "[" and "]" characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you are trying to have an object out of your json response. That is quite easily getable with iterators like `$.each()` in jquery and `for..in` etc with plain js:

You can use this with an iterator like `$.each()`:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/cart_update.php?lang=en',
  //datatype: 'json', // <----add this, this can parse the response as json.
  data: {
    'id': id,
    'incr': increment,
    'quantity': jQuery("#quantity_number" + id).val(),
    'final_quantity': final_quantity,
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data != "") {
      var resp = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // You don't have datatype, so this is required.
      jQuery.each(resp, function(i, obj) {
        jQuery("#quantity_number" + id).val(obj.quantity);
        jQuery("#total" + id).html(obj.price);
      });
    } // if
  }
});
```

If you add `datatype: 'json'` in the ajax options then you don't have to parse the json string as a valid json. `datatype` does this automatically so, you don't have to do it explicitly, the way you are doing.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I had forgotten that I was sending back an array, because it was itself the source to be json-ified. Thanks to all the other contributors for their responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not supress the "[" and "]" characters and parse the response json, it will be an array of objects. You need to loop over this array and inside the loop you can access the properties of each object.
Your current code works for now because most probably you have only one item in array. But if you would get multiple items, your current code will also break.

Answer (score 1):

You can Loop the array and get the results.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj, function(index, value) {
  $("#quantity_number" + id).val(value.quantity);
  $("#total" + id).html(value.price);
});
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

server sent you the list of JSON object, so that's why you need to remove '[' and ']'. Directly parse your data and user array object to iterate over

Following example help you

var data='[{"cantidad": "8", "precio": "$1,756.00"},{"sadsad": "8", "precio": "$1,756.00"}]';

```
    var objs = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //this is an array of objects
    console.log(objs) //objs[0].cantidad,objs[0].precio
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use replace function. just parse the string which is returned. use the below code

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'ajax/cart_update.php?lang=en',
data: { 
    'id': id ,
    'incr' : increment,
    'quantity' : jQuery("#quantity_number" + id).val(), 
    'final_quantity' : final_quantity,
},
success: function(data){
    if(data != ""){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        jQuery("#quantity_number" + id).val(obj[0].quantity);
        jQuery("#total" + id).html(obj[0].price);
    } // if
  }
});
```